# Не редактируется любой компонент в группе vkontakte

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь отредактировать данные в группе средствами `php`, без `api`. Все ранние шаги проходили успешно, а при редактировании группы, будь то описание, название, настройки, любые данные... сохранить их не получается..

В процессе отладки, выявил только что на страницу редактирования группы заходит успешно, а после отправки `post` запроса, никаких изменений не происходит.

Пост запрос следующего вида:

```
$post = array(
    'access'=>'0',
    'act'=>iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', 'save'),
    'addr'=>iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $addr),
    'al'=>'1',
    'category_0'=>'1001',
    'category_1'=>'2015',
    'category_2'=>'3084',
    'description'=>iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $opisanie),
    'gid'=>$club,
    'hash'=>iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $hash),
    'name'=>iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $namegroup),
    'rss'=>'',
    'subject'=>'',
    'website'=>'',
);
$c = HTTP_POST::request("https://vk.com/groupsedit.php", $post, "https://vk.com/".$addr."?act=edit");
```

на выходе получай лишь это:

[image: на выходе получай лишь это:]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Подобные вещи нужно делать **исключительно** через API, а запросами не напрямую к веб-версии.

Нужный метод: https://vk.com/dev/groups.edit
Как проще всего получить пользовательский ключ доступа и вшить его в скрипт: https://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user